# Server Side Rendering - Redux passing state to client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I've been experimenting with SSR with React/Redux and following the tutorial on the [Redux website](https://redux.js.org/recipes/serverrendering). But I am not having success with passing my state from the server to the client through the window. On the client my variable comes back as undefined. I haven't been able to find a way to debug this.

I'm also using typescript to develop but building to JavaScript (unsure if that would give me trouble)

**Server Code**

```
app.get("/reactComponent", function (req, res) {
  var hardCodedState = { person: [{ firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }]};

  const store = createStore(appReducer, hardCodedState); 
  const body = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}> 
      <Data /> 
    </Provider>
  );

  const preloadedState = store.getState();

  res.send(renderHTML(body, preloadedState));
});
function renderHTML(html, preloadedState) {
  return `<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="root">${html}</div>
      <script>
        window.__REDUX_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g,'\\u003c')}
      </script>
      <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>`
}
```

**Client Side**

```
public componentDidMount(){
  axios.get("http://localhost/reactComponent").then(response => {
    const preloadedState = (window as any).__REDUX_STATE__;
    // delete (window as any).__REDUX_STATE__;
    const store = createStore(appReducer,preloadedState);
    hydrate(<Provider store={store}><Data /></Provider>, document.getElementById("content"));
  }).catch(error =>{
    console.log("error",error);
  });
}
```

`const preloadedState = (window as any).__REDUX_STATE__;` always comes back as undefined, so my component never renders on the client from mismatched results on hydrate.

Anything I can try or steps could take to debug the hand off from the server to the client?

Comment: View the HTML source of your page. What is put in`__REDUX_STATE__`  ?

Comment: `window.__REDUX_STATE__ = { person: [{ firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }]}` is what the in the script tag from the renderHTML function. I never see that variable on the client side. I don't know of a way to debug the returned html from the service call

Comment: Then log what `window.__REDUX_STATE__` is in your other part of the application. don't reference it as `(window as any)`. You're setting the global variable fine, if it's not defined later in your code you're either deleting it or have a syntax error

Comment: `(window as any)` is keeping typescript happy. But I put a `console.log` within the script tag of the HTML response and I'm not seeing it anywhere. Which leads me to believe it's not getting run, which would also be the reason the variable isn't getting set.

Comment: Keep debugging. Script tags in the page execute immediately, if you aren't seeing logging there figure out why. Are there javascript errors in the console? Where do console logs work and where do they stop working?